# While using BFG repo cleaner, Can we merge the cleansed branch to main?

Tags: git, github, bfg-repo-cleaner

I am using [BFG repo cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)  to remove secrets from my repository. But as the instructions say to force push my changes to main branch. I am unable to do so because my organisation repo has blocked force push to the repository.

Is there any way to merge my changes onto the main branch (force push blocked branch) ?

I had tried merging my changes from `derived-branch` to `main` but the problem here is only derived branch has its secrets removed not the main after merging.
[`derived-branch` from main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFUo9.png)

[`main` branch after merging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSB0I.png)

`java -jar bfg-1.14.0.jar --replace-text Passwords.txt` this is the command that i use to replace the secrets.

What should i do if my main branch had blocked force push?

Comment: The force push is a must. If you merge the cleaned branch back to the uncleaned one, it means you did nothing meaningful except making the history a mess.

Comment: If you don't have the right to change your main branch history, it implies you cannot use BFG Repo cleaner on your main branch. You have to discuss the point with whoever is in charge of the repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already said in a comment, **you have to force push** otherwise commits with credentials won't be replaced and credentials will always be visible.

So policy preventing force push has to be disabled temporarily.

But as always when credentials are divulgated, you must assume that maybe they have been already discovered and you must revoked them (I.e. change password or regenerate the token).

And if you revoke them (remember, you must do it!), maybe you now don't care about rewriting history...

Answer (score -1):

Generally:

1. Create a PR(Pull Request) on the `main` branch against your `derived-branch` branch.
2. Merge the PR on the `main` branch.
3. Check the commit history(either from browser or from command line using `git log`) to have the commit you raised.

Basically, it seems your changes not merged to `main`

Comment: the changes from `derived-branch` is merged to `main` but the secrets still remain there in the main branch even after merging.